# Combinatorics: Count the number of set partitions into groupings of a certain size

Tags: combinatorics

I have 10 items in a set: $S = \lbrace a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j\rbrace$.

I would like to calculate the number of set partitions, where for each set partition $S$, for all subsets $x\in S$, $2\le  |x| \le 3$.

I see the Bell Equations, and that I can write: 
$$
{10\choose3}*B_3 + {10\choose2}*B_2 
$$

But I can think of reasons why this might be too small of a number, and realize that I haven't actually used the whole Bell Equation (which is making me suspicious that I am doing something wrong).

How many such set partitions are there (and how do I calculate it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To partition $S$ into five pairs, you have ${10 \choose 2}$ ways to choose the first pair, ${8 \choose 2}$ ways to choose the second and so on.  This would give $\frac {10!}{(2!)^5}$ ways but we probably don't care which order we chose the pairs.  The pairs can come out in $5!$ different ways, so there are $\frac {10!}{(2!)^55!}=945$

Similarly, for two partitions of $3$ and two of two we have $10 \choose 3$ways to choose the first set of three, $7 \choose 3$ for the second, and $4 \choose 2$ for the first set of two.  Then there are two pairs we can swap in order, so we get $\frac {10!}{(3!)^2(2!)^2(2!)^2}=6300$

There are a total of $7245$ partitions as you desire.

Comment: excellent--thank you! still trying to put my mind back in the combinatorics, but this looks like it (accepted)..

Comment: Here’s a little quicker way to count what Ross counted: For five pairs, choose the element to pair $a$ with (9 choices). Then choose the element to pair the first remaining unpaired element (7 choices), and so on. That gives $9\times7\times5\times3\times1=945$. With two groups of three, choose the four elements to put into pairs (${10\choose4}=210$), then choose the element to pair the smallest of those with ($3$), and finally choose two elements to group the smallest of the remaining six with (${5\choose2}=10$), so $210\times3\times10=6300$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach based upon generating functions. The following  can be found in section II.3.1 in *[Analytic combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick:

> The class $S^{(A,B)}$ of set partitions with block sizes in $A\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ and with a number of blocks that belongs to $B$ has exponential generating function
>
> \begin{align*}
> S^{(A,B)}(z)=\beta(\alpha(z))\qquad\text{where}\qquad \alpha(z)=\sum_{a\in A}\frac{z^a}{a!},\quad \beta(z)=\sum_{b\in B}\frac{z^b}{b!}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In the current situation we are looking for subsets $x\in S$ with size $2\le |x| \le 3$ and set
\begin{align*}
A=\{2,3\}\qquad\text{where}\qquad\alpha(z)=\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}
\end{align*}
accordingly. Since there is no restriction to the number of partitions we have
\begin{align*}
B={\mathbb{Z}}\qquad\text{where}\qquad \beta(z)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}=\exp(z)
\end{align*}

The resulting generating function is according to (1)
\begin{align*}
\beta(\alpha(z))=\exp\left(\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}\right)\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> Since there are $10$ items in $S$, we are looking for the coefficient $[z^{10}]$ in (2) and calculate
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{10![z^{10}]\exp\left(\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}\right)}
> &=10![z^{10}]\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!} \left(\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}\right)^n\\
> &=10!\sum_{n=0}^5\frac{1}{n!2^n}[z^{10-2n}]\left(1+\frac{1}{3}z\right)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=10!\sum_{n=0}^5\frac{1}{n!2^n}\binom{n}{10-2n}\frac{1}{3^{10-2n}}\tag{4}\\
> &=10!\left(\frac{1}{4!2^4}\binom{4}{2}\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{5!2^5}\binom{5}{0}\frac{1}{1}\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=6300+945\\
> &\color{blue}{=7245}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we factor out $\frac{z^{2n}}{2^n}$. We use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$. We also set the upper limit of the series to $5$ since the exponent of $z^{10-2n}$ is non-negative.
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $z^{10-2n}$.
- In (5) we observe that only two summands provide non-zero contributions, since $\binom{p}{q}=0$ if $q>p$.

Comment: I like this a lot; upvoted; I think it is a great generic approach and cites a good resource; not sure I should switch my accepted answer.

Comment: @bordeo: Good to see the answer is useful! :-)  ... and no reason to switch the accepted answer. You might find *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299814/number-of-possibilities-for-n-persons-at-m-tables-with-at-least-5-persons-per-ta/2309718#2309718)* useful, which also derives a recurrence relation based upon this  method.

Comment: thank you--I will check it out!  (Never would have thought this kind of problem would come up at work)

Answer (score 0):

Under the given rules, there can either be one of two possible outcomes:

1. Five partitions of $S$ where each partition has $2$ elements
2. Four partitions of S where two partitions have $3$ elements and two partitions have $2$ elements.

In the first case, we have $\frac{1}{5!}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}$ different partitions. In the second case we have $\frac{1}{(2!)^2}\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2}$ different partitions. So together we have $\frac{1}{5!}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2} + \frac{1}{(2!)^2}\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2}$  partitions.

Comment: dang.  was thinking that, but really hoped it was only that bellman thing.  Actually, now that I think about it...

Do you think that, say, I choose 2 from ten: (a,b), and I choose 2 from 8: (c,d).  This is the same set partition as (c,d) from ten and (a,b) from 8.  

So shouldn't some of those duplicates be divided out?

Comment: For the first case, you have assumed that the order of the partition matters.  If you just care about the set of partitions, you need to divide by $5!$ different orders of the pairs.  Similarly for case 2 you should divide by $(2!)^2$

Comment: I overlooked that. I'll correct my answer. Thanks.